# Tubus Rack Compatibility on a 29er With Discs

Tags: disc-brake, rack, 29er, compatibility

I have a [Trek 520](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/road/touring/520/520/) with a [Tubus Tara](http://www.rei.com/product/768569/tubus-tara-front-bike-rack) rack on the front and a [Tubus Cargo](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/tubus_racks.asp#Cargo) (*not* the newer Evo model) rack on the rear. I'm thinking about trading in the 520 for a 29er with disc brakes, probably a [Salsa Fargo](http://salsacycles.com/bikes/fargo).

So I guess my question is two parts:

1. Would disc brakes interfere with mounting the racks? And...
2. I know I could run 700c tires on the rim if need be, but would I have the clearance for fat tires as well?

Has anybody tried this?

Comment: I'm not sure about your racks, but I bought a special rear 29er rack. Which gives more clearance. It was by continental I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a salsa Fargo, with the tubus duo and logo racks. The cargo appears to be a more basic logo, so you should be fine for the rear.

The fargo's caliper mounts are inside the rear triangle, and the bike is designed to be a touring bike.

With the duo, you will sacrifice using the fork mounted bottle cage mounts. Its most likely the same for the Tara. That upper loop on the Tara may interfere with a 29er, but I have no first hand experience.